# Android autobahn websocket doesn't disconnect

Tags: android, autobahnws

I'm using websocket in my app to check new messages.
Websocket implemented in my Service class, when i want to stop service (using stopService in Activity) it should call disconnect websocket, but method `onClose` doesn't called

Here is some code:

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    start();

    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("tag", "onDestroy service start");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RepeatingAlarmService.class);

    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0));
    }

    mConnection.disconnect();  // this line doesn't work ???

    super.onDestroy();

    Log.i("tag", "service stopped");
}


private void start() {
    final String uri = "ws://ws.blabla.com"
    try {

        mConnection.connect(uri, new WebSocketConnectionHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onOpen() {
                Log.i("tag", "Socket open"); // this line work well

                super.onOpen();
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
                Log.i("tag", "Socket closed " + String.format("code: %d, reason: %s", code, reason));  // this line doesn't been printed
                }

                super.onClose(code, reason);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextMessage(String payload) {              
                Log.i("tag", payload); // this line work well

                super.onTextMessage(payload);
            }
        });
    } catch(Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: use only latest version of external libraries.

In gradle build file i'm using maven repository "jitpack.io"

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
```

I write this line `compile 'com.github.tavendo:AutobahnAndroid:v0.5.2'` at `dependencies` section to tell gradle that he should download dependendy from jitpack repository.

The latest version on Github is 0.5.2 but if you download it from github (not from jitpack.io) you will see the difference.

Comment: Better will be to report it to creator so he will fix it ... He was quite responsive...

Comment: I tried both of them but they didn't help. When I call disconnect method, it doesn't fire onClose.

Comment: @ayteq what version you are using now? Where it was downloaded?
Please give some code

Comment: @YuriyKolbasinskiy I'm using 0.5.2, I downloaded it from github. Formerly I was using jitpack via gradle. After finding your post here I tried 0.5.2. I downloaded it from github and imported as a module and compiled it in gradle. Problem is when I call socket.disconnect() method, it never disconnects from server, so onClose is not being called. I've fixed this bug via server side hack. I created an event which disconnects user from the socket server.

Comment: @ayteq are you sure, that you removed `compile 'com.github.tavendo:AutobahnAndroid:v0.5.2'` from `dependencies` in Gradle file? I think you still using the old version. Please check it.
Can you find `autobahn*.jar` files in your project folder?

Comment: The autobahn*.jar file I download from their web site is 0.5.0. Where did you download the jar file of 0.5.2, can you share the direct url of it?